# parsec.py recursive definitions

Tags: python, recursion, parsec

I'm loving the simplicity of this library. Sadly I haven't figure out how to make recursive definitions:

Consider this minimal contrived example:

```
import parsec as psc
digit = psc.regex("[0-9]")
number = lambda: digit ^ (digit + number())
_ = number().parse("42")
```

As expected, the evaluation of `number()` is infinite recursive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I know in this specific example it can be solved by changing line 3 to

```
number = lambda: psc.many1(digit)
```

but I'm not sure it's always possible for a general case.

Is it possible to make the parsing of number recursive as in

```
<number> ::= <digit><number> | <digit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(UPDATE) Disclaimer:** As we found out in the comments, this only works with versions of parsec.py *above* 3.3, which (as of August 2018) is the latest release available on PyPI, so for now you have to manually install the development version from GitHub in order for this solution work.

**UPDATE 2:** [parsec.py v3.4](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/releases/tag/v3.4) has finally been released and fixes the issue.

---

In cases like these, I find that it is often helpful to "manually expand" the primitives provided by `parsec` and write a "low-level" parser of our own (i.e. one that takes `text` and `index` arguments, not one built up from parsec primitives), just to see what is going on. By taking the definition of [`try_choice`](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/154baeb360f8e33afe41b75e225d02a49aba8eee/src/parsec/__init__.py#L174-L184) (`^`) from the parsec source code and manually plugging in the constituents of your expression<sup>1</sup>, we can write a parser which I think does what you want:

```
import parsec as psc
digit = psc.regex("[0-9]")

def number():
  @psc.Parser
  def number_parser(text, index):
    res = (digit + number())(text, index)
    return res if res.status else digit(text, index)
  return number_parser

_ = number().parse("42423")
print(_)
```

Output:

```
('4', ('2', ('4', ('2', '3'))))
```

The reason this works is of course because the "parser-returning function" `number()` gets called only conditionally within the actual parser, not (unconditionally) within itself.

An easier way to write this is to not use a "parser-returning function" at all but just write the parser itself directly:

```
@psc.Parser
def number(text, index):
  return ((digit + number) ^ digit)(text, index)
```

The usage changes from `number().parse("42423")` to `number.parse("42423")` but it does the same thing.

Lastly, is there some functionality in parsec.py that lets you do this without the explicit `text` and `index` arguments, such that the parser is built up entirely from other parsec.py primitives? It turns out that [`parsec.generate`](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/154baeb360f8e33afe41b75e225d02a49aba8eee/src/parsec/__init__.py#L355-L377) fits the bill rather nicely! From its [in-source documentation](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/154baeb360f8e33afe41b75e225d02a49aba8eee/src/parsec/__init__.py#L344-L352):

> The most powerful way to construct a parser is to use the generate
>   decorator. The `generate` creates a parser from a generator that
>   should yield parsers. These parsers are applied successively and their
>   results are sent back to the generator using `.send()` protocol. The
>   generator should return the result or another parser, which is
>   equivalent to applying it and returning its result.

You can find example usages [here](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/154baeb360f8e33afe41b75e225d02a49aba8eee/examples/sexpr.py#L37-L51), from which it becomes clear that we can write:

```
@psc.generate
def number():
  r = yield (digit + number) ^ digit
  return r
```

This works because besides all the fancy generator magic it does, the `generate` decorator returns a function which is itself decorated with `@parsec.Parser` (cf. source linked above), so the resulting, fully decorated `number` function will be of the same kind as the one in the 2nd solution. Hence, we can use it in the same manner as `digit` etc. without having to call it or anything, which is what we do in the `yield` expression.

Usage is again just `number.parse("42423")` and it returns the same thing as the other two solutions.

Maybe there is a better solution out there but this is all I could come up with.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I had to reverse the order from `digit ^ (digit + number())` to `(digit + number()) ^ digit`, because the first one returns just the first digit and then considers itself done. I hope this is ok?</sub>

Comment: Your fixed version is actually the example I wanted to show. Your first approach is only detecting the fist digit, the other two are having the same  recursion problems. For fixing them I first defined: `tokenize = lambda p: p + psc.regex(r"\s+|\Z")`. I changed res in the first approach to `res = tokenize(digit)(text, index)`. In the second approach `return (tokenize(digit) ^ digit + number)(text, index)` and in the third approach `r = yield tokenize(digit) ^ (digit + number)`. I'm still not happy with that approach since I'm forced to tokenize.

Comment: @jabozzo My bad, the first example didn't have the change described in the footnote applied (reversed order) - I edited it and it should work fine now. What is the problem with the other two examples? They work fine for me and don't lead to infinite recursion. Or do you mean that it has to be ``digit ^ (digit + number)`` and not the other way round?

Comment: The updated first approach also has infinite recursion problems. I've just copied/pasted your functions into a file one after the other and doing a `try: print(number.parse("24243")) except RecursionError as _: print("Recursion")` in between each redefinition and I get 3 "Recursion". I'ts like in the (digit + number) part, digit is not consuming a character. [Here](https://pastebin.com/tP6VSK5D) is exactly what I'm running.

Comment: @jabozzo Sorry, I just found out that at least the first 2 examples do in fact lead to infinite recursion **if you run them in Python 2**, so I guess that is the fundamental issue here? It works fine for me in Python 3.5, however (which is what I normally use). If I had to guess, I would say this is probably down to how decorators are handled differently between the two versions. The 3rd example doesn't work at all in Python 2 (``SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator``)... Can you switch to Python 3 for your project?

Comment: @jabozzo Oh nevermind, you use Python 3 as well... but if I run your exact code with Python 3.5 it just prints ``('4', ('2', ('4', ('2', '3'))))`` three times, no errors at all... weird.

Comment: in case i'ts relevant I'm in a conda enviroment and installed parsec via pip: `pip3 show parsec \n
Name: parsec
\n Version: 3.3`

Comment: @jabozzo Yes that's probably it, I just tried with your version of parsec and it led to recursion even with Python 3.5 - but if I install the development version directly from Github (``pip install git+https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py.git``) it works fine, so I guess they changed something important since the latest release.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jabozzo You're very welcome, this has been interesting :) From my testing it looks like the bug fix that makes it work in the Github version is [this](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/compare/sighingnow:5ffc232...sighingnow:154baeb#diff-7cbf696ae5cbe98049bd8dc961f10a3dL296), so it's actually a problem with  ``joint`` (``+``).

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to solve this problem if there are already a lot of *parser-returning* functions or just want to be consistent in style is to make the function lazy evaluate:

```
import parsec as psc

def lazy(fn):
  @psc.Parser
  def _lazy(text, index):
    return fn()(text, index)
  return _lazy

digit = lambda: psc.regex("[0-9]")
number = lambda: (digit() + lazy(number)) ^ digit()
print(number().parse("423242"))
```

Prints:

```
('4', ('2', ('3', ('2', ('4', '2')))))
```